Adding contact to success team doesn't show in success team members
In Education Cloud, if I try to add an account under the success team it works and shows there but if I try to add a contact it doesn't show. If I use SOQL, I can see that both are there but the frontend component just doesn't show the contacts. How do I get it to show the contacts or are contacts not meant to show?


Are those members added to a predefined case team - is TeamTemplateId null?

@KrisGoncalves this was a while ago but iirc those were case memebers added directly to a case, not to a predefined case team

I do work at Salesforce for Education Cloud - although I didn't make this component - but, had a hand in the underlying API/queries.
I believe what's going on is the fact that we query against CaseTeamMember to ensure that Member.IsActive = true. Which, if you add a Contact - this'll always be false as there is no applicable isActive field (even if Contact is tied to a User record in my quick testing). When you add members - you'll notice it's People - signifying community users which will have the isActive flag.

As a result, Contacts added to the team directly will not appear.
You can certainly put in a Case to see if product might feel differently for this specific UI component, your use-case, and what I noted above about Contact and the Member.IsActive field.
Though, Success Teams are tied heavily to availability in support which does require a User (ex. to use with scheduling features - service resources) which is why the query is filtering that way.
